# qsort crashing program - C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

Trying to follow [this](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/c/qsort__sorting_array_of_strings__integers_and_structs.xml) example. (Section String sorting...)
Is there anything obvious that would make this crash in stdlib's qsort.c?
I also tried *cstring_cmp* with strncmp specifying 30 chars max, much more than I have.
*fileArray[20] seems to be correctly populated with strings.
Thanks.

```
char* ptr_fileName;  
char* fileArray[20];//number of files  
size_t strings_len;  

ptr_fileName = (char*)malloc((strlen(FindFileData.cFileName)+1)*sizeof(char));
memcpy(ptr_fileName, FindFileData.cFileName, strlen(FindFileData.cFileName)+1);
fileArray[i] = ptr_fileName;



strings_len = sizeof(fileArray) / sizeof(char *);          
qsort(fileArray, strings_len, sizeof(char *), cstring_cmp);   
//crashing in qsort.c
```

qsort c-string compare function:

```
/* qsort C-string comparison function */
    int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
    {
        const char **ia = (const char **)a;
        const char **ib = (const char **)b;
        return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
        /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from
        comparison function */
    }
```

Comment: Why was your question tagged C++? It's C code and you're doing it the (hard) C way.

Comment: can you show the code you used to initialize the strings?

Comment: maybe he used C++ compiler to compile the code and the standards (maybe) have discreapancies, in, say, the way unitialised memory is filled.  This _matters_.

Comment: Still not a minimalistic example reproducing the crash. But by the looks of the shown code, you're trashing memory in the code not shown. You'll also crash if any of the 20 strings in FileArray is NULL or uninitialized.

Comment: example.c:7: error: undefined identifier `i'

Comment: @leeeroy: Yes that is it. I am using 10 strings and have allocated for 20. I wanted to allocate for worst case. Looks like I need to allocate dynamically?

Comment: It looks like you need to assign a different value to strings_len variable, that's equal to the index of the last array element, that you have allocated.  And it also looks like people down there VVVV actually answered your question, so, do not forget to reward one of them them with a green check mark.

Comment: @Tommy:  No, you just need to pass the proper value as strings_len when calling qsort.  If you are telling qsort to sort 20 strings, and you're only giving it 10 strings, OF COURSE it will crash.  If you pass 10 strings, make sure you also pass the number 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you are only filling fileArray with 10 strings, leaving 10 entries uninitialized.

When you call qsort, you pass 20 as the strings_len argument.
This will, of course, result in undefined behavior.

**You have to give qsort accurate information.**

If you are passing 10 strings in the array, you must also pass the number 10 as the number of elements to be sorted.

Note:
If you follow my earlier answer, setting a breakpoint on cstring_cmp, you would quickly see when the compare method is called with invalid data, leading directly to the crash.

Answer (score 2):

How do you populate:

```
char* fileArray[20];
```

as it stands, it's an array of uninitialised pointers.

Comment: Added how I populate the array.

Answer (score 2):

Set a breakpoint in cstring_cmp, and watch as it is called each time.

See if the ultimate crash happens inside cstring_cmp, or in qsort.
Check the state of the fileArray just before the crash.

Answer (score 1):

> *fileArray[20] seems to be correctly populated with strings.

The asterisk before fileArray makes me veeeery suspicious about the correctness of the way you populated the array.
I don't observe anything else that might break your code.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not initialising the contents of fileArray, it legal contains random memory, not legal char pointers.